# Combining IN AND LIKE operators

Tags: mysql

Is there any method to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cores` WHERE superkinds IN ('%altro%', '%feste%')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE superkinds LIKE '%altro%'

OR superkinds LIKE '%feste%'`

Answer (score 2):

Not with `IN`, only with `OR`.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) or [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) with a valid regular expression.

Comment: ...functional, but extra regex overhead and not any less complex than `str LIKE '%x%' OR str LIKE '%y%'`

Comment: If the IN clause was more complicated it could be useful. Not sure how the performance would match up against multiple LIKE's. If I had to guess I would say it wouldn't be much different.